# PHP: Append array in foreach loop with elements on condition with matching elementId

Tags: php, arrays, loops, append

I have an array with with different code numbers, and in turn each code can refer to different items. However, every code can refer to many items, while every item can have many codes (i.e. many-to-many relation between codes and items).

I have the items and I have the item codes, and now I want to append the right codes to the right items via a loop in a code snippet looking this (each $itemCode object includes an $item.Id property):

```
foreach($itemCodes as $itemCode) {

    $itemCodesForItem = [];

    foreach($items as $item) {

        if($itemCode->getItem()->getId() == $item->getId()) {

            array_push($itemCodesForItem, $itemCode->getCode());
            $item->setCode($itemCodesForItem); // Assign with array with all appended codes for a specific item
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that every matching code overwrites the previous matching one, so in the end it only assigns one code to each item. But if an item has several codes, I want all those codes appended in the array for the specific item, and not only the last matching one. Does anyone know how to catch and append the right codes to the right items here?

Comment: Typo: `if($itemCode->getItem()->getId() = $item->getId())`. You're assigning instead of comparing.

Comment: Either way, that would have raised a fatal error, so I doubt it's the cause of the issue. Can you give a small sample of your input arrays and a desired result?

Comment: My bad. I have fixed the comparison now.

Comment: The comparison is fixed, but the issue remains.

Comment: As I said in my second comment, please provide us with some sample values to test your code on.

Comment: Though, `$itemCodesForItem = [];` should probably be inside the first loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, putting the array inside the first loop doesn't work. The issue is that every matching code overwrites the previous matching one, so in the end it only assigns one code to each item. But if an item has several codes, I want all those codes appended in the array for the specific item, and not only the last matching one.

Comment: Then put your assignment after the inner loop is done, once you've gathered all of them.

Comment: I can't put the assignment after the inner loop since the $item variable will only be reachable within the inner loop, or what do you mean? Can you please give a code sample?

Comment: You're right, my mind ran away for a moment. Perhaps items should be the outer loop and itemcodes the inner one?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally I got it working with the following code:

```
foreach($items as $item) {

    $itemCodesForItem = [];

    foreach($itemCodes as $itemCode) {

        while($itemCode->getItem()->getId() == $item->getId()) {

            array_push($itemCodesForItem, $itemCode->getCode());
            $item->setCode($itemCodesForItem);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```